# How to get mapbox-gl-js-offline-example to work?

Tags: javascript, gis, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to get self hosted map tiles working with a Mapbox gl js application. As a starting point, I'm trying to get https://github.com/klokantech/mapbox-gl-js-offline-example/blob/gh-pages/index.html to work. I'm open to other ideas like tileserver-gl-light, but I can't get that to work either.

I'm on Windows 10 and have downloaded the .zip from github and changed two lines in index.html to try to get it to work. You can see all of my commented out attempts.

```
var style = {
  "version": 8,
  "sources": {
    "countries": {
      "type": "vector",
      // "url": "mapbox://map-id"
      // "url": "http://tileserver.com/layer.json", 
      //"tiles": [location.origin+location.pathname+"countries/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"],
      //"tiles": ["http://localhost:8080/data/v3/" + "countries/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"],
      //"tiles": "C:/Users/mattk/Desktop/mapbox-gl-js-offline-example-gh-pages/mapbox-gl-js-offline-example-gh-pages/countries/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf",
      "tiles": "http://localhost:8000/countries/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf",
      "maxzoom": 6
    }
  },
  //"glyphs": location.origin+location.pathname+"font/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
  //"glyphs": "http://localhost:8080/" + "font/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
  //"glyphs": "C:/Users/mattk/Desktop/mapbox-gl-js-offline-example-gh-pages/mapbox-gl-js-offline-example-gh-pages/countries/font/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
  "glyphs": "http://localhost:8000/countries/font/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
  "layers": [{
    "id": "background",
    "type": "background",
    "paint": {
      "background-color": "#ddeeff"
    }
```

When I open up index.html, I can only see the navigational widgets zoom in/out and change bearing to North. Console shows:

```
Uncaught Error: sources.countries.tiles: array expected, string found
    at style_batch.js:45
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Style.<anonymous> (style_batch.js:43)
```

but I'm not sure what to do with that

I'm new to GIS, so I'll appreciate it if you explain it to me like I'm 5.